# How to output one number few times with spaces in one line via bash

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting

How to output one number few times with spaces in one line via bash

I have

```
a=5
b=10
```

I should output 5 times number 10 with using of variables and with spaces
Also, i should capture this in variable

For example, i have to receive this

`10 10 10 10 10`

And it should be variable, it can be array.
But after `echo $c`, i should receive `10 10 10 10 10`

How to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for ((i=1;i<=a;i++)); do export c=$c" ${b}"; done; echo $c
10 10 10 10 10
```